# How filter one big dataframe many times(equal to small df‘s row count) by another small dataframe(row by row) ？

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark dataframe，`dfA` and `dfB`.
I want to filter `dfA` by `dfB`'s each row, which means if `dfB` have 10000 rows, i need to filter dfA 10000 times with 10000 different filter conditions generated by `dfB`. Then, after each filter i need to collect the filter result as a column in `dfB`.

```
dfA                                    dfB
+------+---------+---------+           +-----+-------------+--------------+
|  id  |  value1 |  value2 |           | id  |  min_value1 |  max_value1  |
+------+---------+---------+           +-----+-------------+--------------+            
|  1   |    0    |   4345  |           |  1  |     0       |       3      |
|  1   |    1    |   3434  |           |  1  |     5       |       9      |
|  1   |    2    |   4676  |           |  2  |     1       |       4      |
|  1   |    3    |   3454  |           |  2  |     6       |       8      |
|  1   |    4    |   9765  |           +-----+-------------+--------------+
|  1   |    5    |   5778  |           ....more rows, nearly 10000 rows.
|  1   |    6    |   5674  |
|  1   |    7    |   3456  |
|  1   |    8    |   6590  |
|  1   |    9    |   5461  |
|  1   |    10   |   4656  |
|  2   |    0    |   2324  |
|  2   |    1    |   2343  |
|  2   |    2    |   4946  |
|  2   |    3    |   4353  |
|  2   |    4    |   4354  |
|  2   |    5    |   3234  |
|  2   |    6    |   8695  |
|  2   |    7    |   6587  |
|  2   |    8    |   5688  |
+------+---------+---------+
......more rows,nearly one billons rows
```

**so my expected result is**

```
resultDF
+-----+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id  |  min_value1 |  max_value1  |          results           |
+-----+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+            
|  1  |     0       |       3      | [4345,3434,4676,3454]      |
|  1  |     5       |       9      | [5778,5674,3456,6590,5461] |
|  2  |     1       |       4      | [2343,4946,4353,4354]      |
|  2  |     6       |       8      | [8695,6587,5688]           |
+-----+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

**My stupid solutions is**

```
def tempFunction(id:Int,dfA:DataFrame,dfB:DataFrame): DataFrame ={
    val dfa = dfA.filter("id ="+ id)
    val dfb = dfB.filter("id ="+ id)
    val arr = dfb.groupBy("id")
                 .agg(collect_list(struct("min_value1","max_value1"))
                 .collect()

    val rangArray = arr(0)(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[Row]]   // get range array of id 
    // initial a resultDF to store each query's results
    val min_value1 = rangArray(0).get(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
    val max_value1 = rangArray(0).get(1).asInstanceOf[Int]
    val s = "value1 between "+min_value1+" and "+ max_value1
    var resultDF = dfa.filter(s).groupBy("id")
                                  .agg(collect_list("value1").as("results"),
                                   min("value1").as("min_value1"),
                                   max("value1").as("max_value1"))
    for( i <-1 to timePairArr.length-1){
       val temp_min_value1 = rangArray(0).get(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
       val temp_max_value1 = rangArray(0).get(1).asInstanceOf[Int]
       val query = "value1 between "+temp_min_value1+" and "+ temp_max_value1
       val tempResultDF = dfa.filter(query).groupBy("id")
                                  .agg(collect_list("value1").as("results"),
                                   min("value1").as("min_value1"),
                                   max("value1").as("max_value1"))
       resultDF = resultDF.union(tempResultDF)
       }

  return resultDF
}

def myFunction():DataFrame = {
  val dfA = spark.read.parquet(routeA)
  val dfB = spark.read.parquet(routeB)

  val idArrays = dfB.select("id").distinct().collect()
  // initial result
  var resultDF = tempFunction(idArrays(0).get(0).asInstanceOf[Int],dfA,dfB)
   //tranverse all id 
  for(i<-1 to idArrays.length-1){  
     val tempDF = tempFunction(idArrays(i).get(0).asInstanceOf[Int],dfA,dfB)
     resultDF = resultDF.union(tempDF)
  }
  return resultDF
}
```

**Maybe you don't want to see my brute force code.it's idea is**

```
 finalResult = null;
 for each id in dfB:
    for query condition of this id:
         tempResult = query dfA 
         union tempResult to finalResult
```

I've tried my algorithms, it cost almost 50 hours.

Does anybody has a more efficient way ? Very thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your DFB is small dataset, I am trying to give the below solution.

Try using a `Broadcast Join` like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast

dfA.join(broadcast(dfB), col("dfA.id") === col("dfB.id") && col("dfA.value1") >= col("dfB.min_value1") && col("dfA.value1") <= col("dfB.max_value1")).groupBy(col("dfA.id")).agg(collect_list(struct("value2").as("results"));
```

`BroadcastJoin` is like a `Map Side Join`. This will materialize the smaller data to all the mappers. This will improve the performance by omitting the required sort-and-shuffle phase during a reduce step.

Some points i would like you to avoid:

Never use `collect()`. When a collect operation is issued on a RDD, the dataset is copied to the driver.

If your data is too big you might get memory out of bounds exception.

Try using `take()` or `takeSample()` instead.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help!  Before I read your answers, i didn't know spark  has so abundant join operations. also thanks for your advice about collect() and broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that *when two dataframes/datasets are involved in calculation then join should be performed*. So *join* is a must step for you. But when should you join is the important question.

I would suggest to **aggregate and reduce rows in dataframes as much as possible before joining as it would reduce shuffling**.

In your case **you can reduce only dfA as you need exact dfB with a column added from dfA meeting the condition**

So you can `groupBy` *id* and aggregate *dfA* so that you get one row of each *id*, then you can perform the *join*. And then you can use a `udf` function for your logic of calculation

comments are provided for clarity and explanation

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//udf function to filter only the collected value2 which has value1 within range of min_value1 and max_value1 
def selectRangedValue2Udf = udf((minValue: Int, maxValue: Int, list: Seq[Row])=> list.filter(row => row.getAs[Int]("value1") <= maxValue && row.getAs[Int]("value1") >= minValue).map(_.getAs[Int]("value2")))


dfA.groupBy("id")              //grouping by id
  .agg(collect_list(struct("value1", "value2")).as("collection"))  //collecting all the value1 and value2 as structs
  .join(dfB, Seq("id"), "right")          //joining both dataframes with id
  .select(col("id"), col("min_value1"), col("max_value1"), selectRangedValue2Udf(col("min_value1"), col("max_value1"), col("collection")).as("results"))  //calling the udf function defined above
```

which should give you

```
+---+----------+----------+------------------------------+
|id |min_value1|max_value1|results                       |
+---+----------+----------+------------------------------+
|1  |0         |3         |[4345, 3434, 4676, 3454]      |
|1  |5         |9         |[5778, 5674, 3456, 6590, 5461]|
|2  |1         |4         |[2343, 4946, 4353, 4354]      |
|2  |6         |8         |[8695, 6587, 5688]            |
+---+----------+----------+------------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Yes, it works.but I still have a small question: Is collect_list() a shuffle operation? Thank you for your help many times.

Comment: groupBy  is shuffling. collect_list is just aggregating on the shuffled groups.